# Counting new Customers per Month

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am crazy confused about this for some reason.

Basically, I'm looking for a query that will find the number of new customers per month, since 2010.

I have the customer's email address(email), all orders placed(OrderID), and what date it was placed on(OrderDate). The table is tblOrder.

I know that a "new customer" is: (a) someone who's never ordered *before* the date/month and (b) who has at least one order *after* the date/month

I'd want the output to be something like this in the end, with a simpler method being better:

```
      01   02   03   04   05   06   07   08   09   10   11   12
2010  ##   ##   ##   ##   ##   ##   ##   ##   ##   ##   ##   ##
2011  ##   ##   ##   ##   ##   ##   ##   ##   ##   ##   ##   ##
2012  ##   ##   ##   ##   ##   ##   ##   ##   ##   ##   ##   ##
```

---

And I was given this to work with, but guys, I'm seriously not a programmer, and it may look simple to some of y'all but it's over my head and not clicking with me at all.

```
SELECT <customer info> 
FROM <customer table> 
WHERE (SELECT COUNT(<order info>) 
    FROM <order table> 
    WHERE <customer info> = <current customer> 
        AND <date> < <target date>) = 0 
        AND (SELECT COUNT(<order info> 
            FROM <order table> 
            WHERE <customer info> = <current customer> 
            AND <date> > <target date>) > 0
```

I know this isn't valid SQL either. So I don't know what to do with it. And I think it just pulls a list of applicable customers (meaning those who haven't ordered before the inputted month) rather than counting them all up and totaling them like I ultimately want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
select yr, [1], [2], [3], [4], [5], [6], [7], [8], [9], [10], [11], [12]
from
(select datepart(month,minDate) mth, datepart(year,minDate) yr, count(*) cnt
 from (select min(OrderDate) minDate, max(OrderDate) maxDate
       from tblOrder
       group by email) sq
 where datediff(month, minDate, maxDate) > 0
 group by datepart(month,minDate), datepart(year,minDate)) src
PIVOT
(max(cnt) 
 for mth in ([1], [2], [3], [4], [5], [6], [7], [8], [9], [10], [11], [12]) ) pvt
```

SQLFiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/06237/6).

Comment: From what I can tell, this is the most accurate answer based on the results I'm getting. I'm not sure how to confirm it for sure, but for now thank you so much!

Comment: @spazzie: Well, you could take my word for it ... ;) More seriously, if there are fewer than a million rows involved, you could dump your table into Excel, then check your results there.

Answer (score 1):

Start by defining a new customer

```
select distinct FirstTimer.customer_id 
from
(select customer_id,min(order_date) as FirstOrderDate
from tblOrder 
group by customer_id
having Month(min(order_date))=month(TargetDate) and
       year(min(order_date))=year(targetDate)
) FirstTimer
join tblOrder ot on ot.customer_id=First_timer.customer_id
where ot.order_date > target_date
```

The first part finds all customers whose first order was in the indicated month.   You then only want those customer who ALSO met the second condition (ordered after the target date)

Without table names and structures, can't create the entire query, but hope the above should give you a bit of a start

Comment: The table name is up there! "customer's email address(email), all orders placed(OrderID), and what date it was placed on(OrderDate). The table is tblOrder" but thank you! I'll definitely look into this closer.

Answer (score 0):

This will get you your new customer counts by year and month:

```
;WITH cteCustFirstMonth As
(   -- Gets the first order date for each active customer
    SELECT   email, 
             MIN(OrderDate)        as FirstOrderDate,
             YEAR(MIN(OrderDate))  as Yr,
             MONTH(MIN(OrderDate)) as Mnth
    FROM     tblOrder
    GROUP BY email
)
-- Groups the first order dates into Year and Month
SELECT   Yr,
         Mnth,
         COUNT(email) As cnt
FROM     cteFirstOrderDate
GROUP BY Yr, Mnth
ORDER BY Yr, Mnth
```

It doesn't return them in the same format that you requested them, but that can be done in excel or in SQL with a little extra work.

Answer (score 0):

Slight edit to @Mark Bannister's answer. The OP's stated intent is to capture the number of new customers by the month in which they placed their first order.  OP's definition of "new customer" is confusing in that he specifies:

> a "new customer" is: (a) someone who's never ordered before the
>   date/month and (b) who has at least one order **after** the date/month (emphasis added)

Maybe this is truly what the OP wants, but this would more accurately be called a "new customer who becomes a repeat buyer in a subsequent month" as it eliminates:

1. Customers who only place one order
2. Customers who place all their orders in the same date/month

@Mark's solution correctly(?) eliminates these customers as [his SQL FIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/06237/6) shows that Fred@home is NOT counted as a new customer.

However, OP also states at the end of his post that "applicable customers" are:

> those who haven't ordered before the inputted month

So to capture ALL new customers (which is what I think the OP is really after), we can still use @Mark's nice PIVOT solution and all we need to do is look at the min(OrderDate) and simply ignore the maxDate comparison as shown below:

```
select yr, [1], [2], [3], [4], [5], [6], [7], [8], [9], [10], [11], [12]
from
(select datepart(month,minDate) mth, datepart(year,minDate) yr, count(*) cnt
 from (select min(OrderDate) minDate
       from tblOrder
       group by email) sq
 group by datepart(month,minDate), datepart(year,minDate)) src
PIVOT
(max(cnt) 
 for mth in ([1], [2], [3], [4], [5], [6], [7], [8], [9], [10], [11], [12]) ) pvt
```

A quick check to verify that all customers are captured can be done by summing all the counts in the pivot table (quick and easy in Excel) and comparing to:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT(email)) FROM tblOrder
```

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT EXTRACT(MONTH FROM orderdate) AS month,
       EXTRACT(YEAR FROM orderdate)  AS year, 
       COUNT(*) 
FROM (
       SELECT MIN(orderdate) AS orderdate, name
       FROM tblOrder
       GROUP BY name
     )
GROUP BY EXTRACT(MONTH FROM orderdate),
         EXTRACT(YEAR FROM orderdate)
```