# Listing New Customers Per Month

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

This is kind of a part two to [a previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17242718/counting-new-customers-per-month) I asked and already got an answer for.

There I had wanted a count of all new customers per month, per year. Now I want to actually see a list of who is new, by email address (but I don't really understand the code that answered that question, so I'm still lost as to doing it myself and, more importantly, confirming it's correct).

The result would ideally just be one column of email addresses. For example:

**New Customers in June 2011**

```
Month
email1@abc.com
email2@def.net
email3@ghi.edu
```

If it's not too complicated to do, bunching them into groups by month would also work. Meaning...

**New Customers in 2011**

```
Jan      Feb      Mar
email1   email4   email7
email2   email5   email8
email3   email6   email9
```

...and so on. I might almost prefer the simpler one of only showing a month at a time though, for my sake of being able to try and understand, haha.

The criteria is pretty straight-forward:

- A list of all customers who placed their first order ever in June of the year 2011.
- And from my first question: I know that a "new customer" is defined as (a) someone who's *never ordered before* June 1, 2011 and (b) who has *at least one order after* June 1, 2011.

My table is called **tblOrders**.
My emails are called **Email**.
Dates are **OrderDate**.

And note that easier code is better for me to understand, unless it's not possible to keep it simple here. This query does seem straight-forward to me... I get the logic, but not how to actually do it! :(

If you need any other info, please ask! Thank you!

**Edit**: If it helps, I was given this faux-code to work off of before, but it's beyond me. /dumb

```
SELECT <customer info> 
FROM <customer table> 
WHERE (SELECT COUNT(<order info>) 
    FROM <order table> 
    WHERE <customer info> = <current customer> 
        AND <date> < <target date>) = 0 
        AND (SELECT COUNT(<order info> 
            FROM <order table> 
            WHERE <customer info> = <current customer> 
            AND <date> > <target date>) > 0
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following query gets you the first order date for each customer:

```
select email, min(orderdate) as FirstOrderDate
from orders o
group by email;
```

To get the count of new customers by month:

```
select year(FirstOrderDate) as yr, month(FirstOrderDate) as mon, count(*)
from (select email, min(orderdate) as FirstOrderDate
      from orders o
      group by email
     ) oc
group by year(FirstOrderDate), month(FirstOrderDate);
```

To get the customers for a given month:

```
select email
from (select email, min(orderdate) as FirstOrderDate
      from orders o
      group by email
     ) oc
where FirstOrderDate >= '2013-01-01' and
      FirstOrderDate < '2013-02-01'
```

Getting them in parallel lists (multiple columns) is probably not worth the effort.

Comment: The answers this is giving me are totally different than the query I got from another guy helping me count the totals per month! But, I think yours are checking out so far... so thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT MIN(OrderDate) AS MOD FROM dbo.tblOrders;
```

gives you the smalest OrderDate in your table.

```
SELECT Email, MIN(OrderDate) AS MOD 
FROM dbo.tblOrders
GROUP BY Email;
```

gives you the first order's date per unique email address.

```
SELECT Email, MIN(OrderDate) AS MOD 
FROM dbo.tblOrders
GROUP BY Email
HAVING MIN(OrderDate) >= '20110601' AND MIN(OrderDate) < '20110701';
```

gives you the desired customer's emails together with their first OrderDate.

To get to your second requirement you just need to remove the `<` part of the `HAVING` clause:

```
SELECT Email, MIN(OrderDate) AS MOD 
FROM dbo.tblOrders
GROUP BY Email
HAVING MIN(OrderDate) >= '20110601';
```

That gives you all customers that have ordered on or after 2011-06-01, but not before.

Comment: Your results are matching up with the guy below's, giving me confidence that you're both right. :P Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Here It.. For the current months

```
 SELECT COUNT(ID) as permnt
    FROM tbl_CustomerDetails 
    where datepart(month,CreatedDate)= datepart(month,GETDATE())
```

Answer (score 0):

**Here It is  For the current month working good ....Sql**

SELECT COUNT(ID) as newpermonth 
FROM dbo.tblOrders
GROUP BY ID
HAVING MIN(OrderDate) >=  DATE_FORMAT(Sysdate(),'%Y-%m-01')  AND MIN(OrderDate) <  DATE_FORMAT(Sysdate(),'%Y-%m-31')