# R - count new customers per year and % of customers that bought the year before

Tags: r, conditional-statements, analysis

I have a very big dataset of customers with dates (years) when they purchased something. I would like R to give me:

1. the number of new customers per year, and
2. the % of customers from the year before (n-1).

My data looks like this:

```
customer_id     year    
12001           2007 
12001           2008 
12001           2009
12002           2006
12002           2007
12003           2005
...             ...
```

where each customer did various purchases over time.

The outputs I would like to have is something like this:

```
# Table1
year    no. of new customers
2005          34
2006          25
2007          17
...          ...
```

Table 1 reports the unique new values per year; and:

```
# Table2
year    % of customers that also purchased at (year-1)
2005       25%
2006       17%
...        ...
```

This Table 2 says *"of all the customers recorded in 2005, 25% were also recorded in 2004; of all the customers recorded in 2006, 17% were also recorded in 2006; etc."*

I know the first part was [partially answered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17242718/counting-new-customers-per-month) but it doesn't apply to R. And I couldn't find anything similar asked elsewhere.

Comment: You need to provide both data set and desired output that corresponds to the data set provided. As it stands right now, it seems you provide a too small data set and some imaginary desired output that has nothing to do with the provided data set. This type of behavior usually makes users to skip your question and move on, while it could be easily answered in theory

Answer (score 2):

Unless I've misunderstood something, the following could help:

```
tab = table(DF)
tab
#           year
#customer_id 2005 2006 2007 2008 2009 2010
#      12001    0    0    1    1    1    0
#      12002    0    1    1    0    0    0
#      12003    1    0    0    0    0    0
#      12004    1    0    1    0    0    0
#      12006    0    0    0    1    0    0
#      12007    0    0    0    1    1    0
#      12008    0    0    0    0    0    1

#new customers per year
as.data.frame(table(factor(colnames(tab)[max.col(tab, "first")], colnames(tab))))
#  Var1 Freq
#1 2005    2
#2 2006    1
#3 2007    1
#4 2008    2
#5 2009    0
#6 2010    1

#pct
as.data.frame(as.table((colSums((tab[, -1] == tab[, -ncol(tab)]) * (tab[, -1] == 1)) / colSums(tab[, -1])) * 100))
#  Var1      Freq
#1 2006   0.00000
#2 2007  33.33333
#3 2008  33.33333
#4 2009 100.00000
#5 2010   0.00000
```

Where "DF":

```
DF = structure(list(customer_id = c(12001L, 12001L, 12001L, 12002L, 
12002L, 12003L, 12004L, 12004L, 12006L, 12007L, 12007L, 12008L
), year = c(2007L, 2008L, 2009L, 2006L, 2007L, 2005L, 2005L, 
2007L, 2008L, 2008L, 2009L, 2010L)), .Names = c("customer_id", 
"year"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -12L))
```

Answer (score 0):

Generate some sample data

```
set.seed(31)
nSamples=5000
df<-data.frame(id=sample(12001:12100,nSamples,replace=T),
               year=sample(2001:2014,nSamples,replace=T))
```

You can use table to determine how many purchases per customer per year

```
t_purchasePerYear<-table(df$year,df$id)
```

Then you can get the change in the number of customers per year

```
nCustPerYear <- apply(t_purchasePerYear,1,function(x){sum(x>0)})
nCustPerYear
nYear = length(nCustPerYear)
nNewCustPerYear <- nCustPerYear[2:nYear] - nCustPerYear[1:(nYear-1)]
nNewCustPerYear
```

Make a second table of the customers that bought this year but not last

```
t_didBuyThisYearAndLast <- t_purchasePerYear[2:nYear,]>0 & t_purchasePerYear[1:(nYear-1),]>0
```

Now get the number of custormers that bought this year and last

```
nBuyThisYearAndLast <- apply(t_didBuyThisYearAndLast,1,function(x){sum(x)})
nBuyThisYearAndLast
```

Divide by the number of customers per year to get the percent

```
pcntBuyThisYearAndLast <- nBuyThisYearAndLast / nCustPerYear[2:nYear] *100
pcntBuyThisYearAndLast
```